# Fb System User: do I need a page access token for "assigned pages" to work?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-marketing-api

I'm using a [Facebook marketing-API system user](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/businessmanager/systemuser/) to create some ads. The posts for those ads are created as a fb page.

In the [business settings](https://business.facebook.com/settings/system-users), I've assigned that page as an "assigned asset" to the system user. This worked, since:

```
GET /me/assigned_pages
```

returns:

```
[{"id": "1027844850652657",
  "tasks": ["ANALYZE", "ADVERTISE", "MODERATE", "CREATE_CONTENT", "MANAGE"]
...
```

However, when I try to access any post on that page or the page itself:

```
GET /1027844850652657`
```

I get:

> OAuthException, code: 10, message: (#10) To use 'Page Public Content Access', your use of this endpoint must be reviewed and approved by Facebook.

So this "assigned page" thing doesn't appear to have any effect.

Curiously `GET /me/accounts` returns `[]`.

What's the recommended way to access posts on a page I created with the system user? Do I really have to use the `manage_pages` permission for my app, to request a Page Access Token on behalf of my system user?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- You do need a Page Token.
- Page Public Content Access is for access to Pages you do NOT own - of course, only for read access.
- If /me/accounts does not return anything, you will not have any Page Token. Of course you have to authorize with `manage_pages` to get access to your Pages.
- Alhtough, if you only want to read Page posts, you can apply for Page Public Content Access and forget about the Page Token.